# variability + singular or plural verb

Tags: plural-forms, singular

The sentence is

> Variability in data is considered a nuisance.
>
> Variability in data are considered a nuisance.

Initially I thought `is` was the correct one, but it was corrected to be `are`. I want to know the reason.

Comment: You were right.  *Is* is correct.  "Variability in data" is taken as a whole to be a singular subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is correct, and the second is incorrect. "Variability in data" is singular, and "is" is the correct form for singular, not "are".

Your second question, why someone else wanted you to use "are", can only be answered by that person, I think.